# nopdfAutorotate in cups default options

Tags: cups

Hi in CUPS I need to add default option `nopdfAutorotate`, I try to add it by

```
lpoptions -p test2 -o nopdfAutoRotate
```

but after I check  `lpoptions -p test2 -l` nothing I changed, any tips how can I add this nopdfAutorotate as default for my printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

> lpoptions -p test2 -o nopdfAutoRotate-default